# publishcreate, publishupdate does not work on associated collection in sailsjs

Tags: associations, sails.js, sails-mongo

i'm totally new to sails association.
        i want to publish (publishCreate and publishUpdate) socket events in associated collection.

i got one solution on [Sails publish(Update) system does not propagate to associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27254587/sails-publishupdate-system-does-not-propagate-to-associations)
my code is like

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    title: 'string',
    owner:{
        model:'user'
    }
  },

  afterUpdate: function(post, cb){

    User.publishUpdate(post.owner, {/* props you want to send */});
    cb();

  }
};
```

But it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

you have to subscribe to this model using the .subscribe() method to receive the message, check the docs: http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/websockets/resourceful-pubsub/publishUpdate.html

Comment: Hi tcruz ,Thanks for response. I want to publish associated populated collection fields,  I also used that code. but , that doesn't fire associated collection.